# How to make requests from different IP addresses on Google Cloud Platform or AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I am building a software that will consume a third-party API which limits my connection at 1200 requests per minute (from the same IP address).

Since this limitation is very low for me, I've been wondering if there's a way to have a set of IP addresses (let's say 100 addresses) and manage the queue so that once an IP exceeds the limitation, the next request will be made from a new one.

Comment: May I ask about the nature of this 3rd party API?  If they are constraining the requests at 1200/minute ... do they not have a reason for that?  I'd suggest contacting the supplier of that API and asking if you can maybe obtain an exception or if they are willing to let you purchase additional access.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is inappropriate to ask for assistance with mechanisms designed for defeating, circumventing, or otherwise violating a site's acceptable use policy.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot actually their own support team suggested me to send requests from different IPs. They don't have any IP whitelisting feature, this is why they suggested this.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Your will need two or more VPC networks. If you only have the default one, create an additional one. Each network adapter will connect to one VPC network.

Create a VM instance with two or more vCPUs. While creating the instance, attach a second network adapter connected to the second VPC network.

In your software, instead of creating a socket on `0.0.0.0`, you create a socket for each network adapter private IP address. Ping pong back and forth between adapters spreading your traffic across your public IP addresses.

You can do the same type of configuration on AWS.